# HTTPServletResponse method setStatus()

Tags: javascript, java, http, jsp, servlets

I've got a jsp with a form that sends an ajax to a servlet in java.
I wanted to send an error (if the login failed) to the jsp from the servlet, and I found the method setStatus(int sc, java.lang.String sm) for the HTTPServletResponse class but its use is deprecated. I wanted to know if there was a way to use setStatus(int sc) while sending a custom error message to the jsp and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [sendError](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int,%20java.lang.String)) instead

Comment: And how should i use it in the JSP?

Comment: Just check the ajax response sent by the servlet and use it as you like, another choice can be to send a json response containing error code and message

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to bother you again. I'm not quite sure how to check the response from the ajax call. Could you recommend me some tutorials maybe? Thank you so much

Comment: @somethingsomething check the status property on `XMLHttpRequest`, Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp